# How do I encrypt and store private messages?

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-4, public-key-encryption

I am developing a private messaging system for my website using Laravel 4, and I want to ensure that the messages remain private.  So far, I have the following code written:

```
class PkeyEncryption {

    public static function encrypt($input, $cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128) {

        $key = sha1(microtime(true) . mt_rand(10000, 90000));

        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_size($cipher, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

        return mcrypt_encrypt($cipher, $key, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $iv);
    }

    public static function decrypt($data, $key, $cipher = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128) {

        $iv = $data['iv'];
        $data = $data['data'];

        return mcrypt_decrypt($cipher, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $iv);
    }
}
```

So, I know how to encrypt the messages, and I also know that I can store the IV alongside the message.  But, I don't know where I am supposed to store the public key.  I have already read a few other questions on the site, and I still haven't found an answer.  Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Note that if the web server has access to the decryption information (key and IV) then an attacker able to compromise the web server will have access to it, too.

Comment: Store the key client-sided (e.g. in a cookie?)

Comment: So I could store the keys off site or on another server?

Comment: just store in db, encrypting them in this context is pointless

Comment: The messages, if stored in a database, will remain private so long as the database credentials are not exposed. Passwords, because they are so sensitive, are (or at least should be) hashed before being entered to the db, in case hackers gain access to the db. Filesystem access would allow the hacker to gain access to the db as well as the encryption/decryption algorithm, which as @Dagon remarked, makes encrypting the messages that are stored in a db, well, pointless.

Comment: Well, could I store the messages somewhere outside of the db?

Comment: sure flat file on the server, less flexible -equivalent level of security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store all users public keys on the server and only the users themselves should have their own private keys.

When user A wants to send message to user B, he will take user B public key and encrypt the message with it. This message can then be decrypted only with the user B private key.

Comment: So would user B have to be in physical possession of his/her private key?

Comment: Indeed. This is achieved with SSL certificates. Asymmetric cryptography.